# Date Diff Calculating Incorrectly When Refreshed On Sunday

Tags: powerbi, dax, datediff

I have added a column as part of my calendar date table that calculates calendar "Weeks from today", please see DAX below :

```
Weeks From Today 2 =
VAR Offset =
    WEEKDAY ( 'Calendar_Table'[Date], 2 )
RETURN
    INT ( TODAY () - ( 'Calendar_Table'[Date] - Offset ) ) / 7
```

[image]

Note - Use of offset to achieve Mon to Sunday week

I use this to filter my reports for certain calendar weeks i.e current or previous week.

Sunday Problem
During the week the field works correctly so for example at the date of creating this post 12th August, when the field is filtered to weeks from today = 0 (i.e current week). It will return all dates between Monday 8th August and 14th August.

> > > Peppearson_1-1660308920704.png not found!

However when I refresh the report on a Sunday this filter returns dates from the next week (not current calendar week).

My report is currently only refreshed on Sunday's so my workaround is to set all relevant weeks from today filters to 1 instead of 0 so that they return the correct dates.

Any ideas what might be causing this issue on a Sunday?

Comment: What is the first day of week - mon?

Comment: Yes the first day of the every week is Monday.
So today I've refreshed my dataset and it is now showing today which should be considered as part of this current calendar week being "1" week from today instead 0 (considering it's Sunday.

Comment: Please, check the answer. It would be nice to have a feedback from you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is nice and smart. Only one thing you need to edit. Let's look into the formula first:

```
TODAY()=14 aug 2022
'Calendar_Table'[Date]=14 aug 2022
WEEKDAY ( 'Calendar_Table'[Date], 2 )=7
```

So, the return part is:

```
(14 aug 2022 -(14 aug 2022 -7))/7 => 7/7 = 1
```

For other dates it works because of INT() rounds down expression to 0. But on Sunday INT() doesn't infuence the result.

To resolve the problem just add `(-1)` when you calculate the Offset:

```
VAR Offset =
    WEEKDAY ( 'Calendar_Table'[Date], 2 )-1
```

I replaced today() with 13 of aug 2022.
[image]

With TODAY() = 14 aug 2022 (Sunday case) result will be the same. You can see it on picture below.

```
 (14 aug 2022 -(14 aug 2022 -6))/7 => 6/7 
 INT(6/7)=0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This slight amendment solved this issue

Comment: Great, glad to help you